# Ensure image, header, paragraph and button remain level, with different length size for header and paragraph

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to achieve is all images the same level, all headers and paragraphs level no matter what length they are and a button after which as all in the same level... I am also trying to make a 9x9 grid, but as soon as I add more columns they start going next to each other not by the underneath...

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex-container .box {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Slabo 27px", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.box p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="box">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x600" alt="" width="400" height="300" style="max-width:90%;height:auto;" />
      </a>
      <h2>Example Header</h2>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod eget mi at cursus. Nam aliquet dolor eros, in varius diam tincidunt et. Curabitur porta nunc arcu, sed mattis felis interdum ut. </p>
      <div>
        <a href="/" class="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x600" alt="" width="400" height="300" style="max-width:90%;height:auto;" />
      </a>
      <h2>Longer example of a header blah </h2>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod eget mi at cursus. Nam aliquet dolor eros, in varius diam tincidunt et. Curabitur porta nunc arcu, sed mattis felis interdum ut. Curabitur consequat non nunc et tempus. Mauris
        porta orci augue, in sagittis eros semper rutrum. Nam in elit mattis, auctor enim a, tempus arcu. In interdum eu lorem sit amet ullamcorper.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="/" class="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x600" alt="" width="400" height="300" style="max-width:90%;height:auto;" />
      </a>
      <h2>another short example </h2>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod eget mi at cursus. Nam aliquet dolor eros, in varius diam tincidunt et. Curabitur porta nunc arcu, sed mattis felis interdum ut. Curabitur consequat non nunc et tempus. Mauris
        porta orci augue, in sagittis eros semper rutrum. Nam in elit mattis, auctor enim a, tempus arcu. In interdum eu lorem sit amet ullamcorper. Proin est ipsum, rutrum ac est ut, mollis mollis elit. Curabitur eget dolor gravida, rhoncus arcu eget,
        rhoncus ante. Nulla rhoncus in mauris et consequat. </p>
      <div>
        <a href="/" class="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is currently the best I have, I've got all images and header and text to be the same level but as soon as I have the buttons in level the headers or paragraphs wont be level... Any help on this would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok to set some heights and some `overflow: hidden;` you could do this:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.flex-container .box {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 30px;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Slabo 27px", serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  /* ! */
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 3.6em;
}

.box p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  /* ! */
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 12.6em;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #008CBA;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
}

/* ! */
.fade {
  position: relative;
  height: 3.6em;
}
/* ! */
.fade:after {
  content: "";
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 1.2em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="box">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x600" alt="" width="400" height="300" style="max-width:90%;height:auto;" />
      </a>
      <div>
        <h2 class="fade">Example Header</h2>
        <p class="fade"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod eget mi at cursus. Nam aliquet dolor eros, in varius diam tincidunt et. Curabitur porta nunc arcu, sed mattis felis interdum ut. </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="/" class="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x600" alt="" width="400" height="300" style="max-width:90%;height:auto;" />
      </a>
      <h2 class="fade">Longer example of a header blah blah blah </h2>
      <p class="fade"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod eget mi at cursus. Nam aliquet dolor eros, in varius diam tincidunt et. Curabitur porta nunc arcu, sed mattis felis interdum ut. Curabitur consequat non nunc et tempus. Mauris
        porta orci augue, in sagittis eros semper rutrum. Nam in elit mattis, auctor enim a, tempus arcu. In interdum eu lorem sit amet ullamcorper.</p>
      <div>
        <a href="/" class="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x600" alt="" width="400" height="300" style="max-width:90%;height:auto;" />
      </a>
      <h2 class="fade">another short example </h2>
      <p class="fade"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod eget mi at cursus. Nam aliquet dolor eros, in varius diam tincidunt et. Curabitur porta nunc arcu, sed mattis felis interdum ut. Curabitur consequat non nunc et tempus. Mauris
        porta orci augue, in sagittis eros semper rutrum. Nam in elit mattis, auctor enim a, tempus arcu. In interdum eu lorem sit amet ullamcorper. Proin est ipsum, rutrum ac est ut, mollis mollis elit. Curabitur eget dolor gravida, rhoncus arcu eget,
        rhoncus ante. Nulla rhoncus in mauris et consequat. </p>
      <div>
        <a href="/" class="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Flow fade `thing` is from [here](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/) where you can also find some other approaches to your problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, still cant get it into a 9x9 grid, and not so sure on the fade flow approach, but thank you :)